# android , downloaded file image does not exist?

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, storage

I am new in android and I am using Android Asynchronous Http Client library to download image file from server
but when I am trying to download images the status is success but the image does not downloaded in the internal storage !!

here is my code

```
download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(url, new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(FullImageActivity.this) {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }
            });
        }
    });
```

any help please !?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Picasso` for image loading & downloading.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Edit:
If you want to download and save to external storage, first download the image:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Then save to the sdCard:

```
void saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ; 

    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), ".YOUR_DIRECTORY"); //Replace with the name of the directory you want.
    folder.mkdir(); 
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename + ".jpg"); //Assuming your image's extension is '.jpg' .
    if (!file.exists()) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); //Again, assuming it's '.jpg' .
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i use it to load image in imageview .. but how can I download that image to internal storage ( gallery ) in high resolution !? can you help me with example or code snippet ?!

Comment: Have you added: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
to your manifest?

Comment: yeah ... i think if i did not add it before thats will cause a permission crash!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the library, but based on the callbacks definitions and on the documentation - the file will not just automatically be saved anywhere on the device. The response comes back in `byte[] response` and it is your responsibility to save it or use it the way you want.

Comment: sounds good ,,, but how can i save it ?! please help me if you know

Comment: Never mind. I was too tired when I answered. I was looking at the callbacks for `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` which return a byte[]. You are actually using `FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler` and you should be fine having the response in File, not byte[].

Answer (score 0):

see this library for android: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Very simple to use:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(img);
```

Comment: its loading url image into imageview .. i want to DOWNLOAD the image in internal storage